# How to write a method X that waits for another method Y to be called and returns the result of method Y?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have an example class

```
export class Data {
    private dataStore = {}

    updateData(name, value): void {
        this.dataStore[name] = value;
    }

    waitForDataUpdate(name): unknown {
        // Should wait and return the value for {name} when {name} is updated via updateData method
    }
}
```

As my comment describes, the goal here is to be able to call `waitForDataUpdate("test")` first, and have it wait for when `updateData("test", "update")` is called (sometime in the future) and then return `update`.

**No additional library dependencies, just node and typescript.**

I'm not sure what knowledge I'm missing, I've looked into promises and while *promising* I can't see how it would fit. I looked into node event emitters and having `waitForDataUpdate()` respond to an event `updateData()` emits would make sense but then there's no way to wait for a result when `waitForDataUpdate()` is called (aka, can't use `await` for example).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you used Promises?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main ideas of node.js is non-blocking APIs.
In means that You **can't** block the execution of some function and jump to execution of some another one.

The basic technique to do what You want is to use events/subscriptions.
The very simple example of this is to put the code that should execute **after** `waitForDataUpdate()` inside a callback:

```js
class Data {
  private callback : null | (() => void)

  update() {
    if (this.callback) this.callback()

    this.callback = null
  }
  onUpdate(callback : () => void) {
    this.callback = callback
  }
}

let data = new Data

data.onUpdate(() => {
  console.log('update')
})
```

All other approaches are derived from this.
Classes like `EventEmitter`, packages like `ts-events`, `Promise` class and `async/await` syntax all do exactly this.